Redirect ASMX on one domain to another ASMX on another domain
I have an asmx web service on a server running Windows Server 2019 and IIS 10.
oldapp.com/services/service1.asmx
I want to redirect the consumption of that service to another domain on that same server
newapp.com/services/service1.asmx
I have created a rule with the IIS Rewrite module and it works fine.

When I enter the first url it redirects me perfectly to the other.
The problem is when consuming it using an old application made in ASP.NET Webforms. I get the following error
Document Moved
Object Moved This document may be found   https://newapp.com/services/service1.asmx
I have installed the Application Request Routing module and activated the proxy server as suggested in another answer but it still does not work.
I don't know what the cause is.
I have added the parameter AllowAutoRedirect = true in the code. Now it does the redirect but gives another error
The client encountered the response content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but 'text/xml' was expected.
I'm starting to think it simply can't be done. SOAP does not support redirection.

In that old webforms application, have you allowed following redirects in whatever thing you are using to query the web service?

You should edit this post to include your rewrite configuration

I added the rewrite rule. The redirect works. If I enter the old service, I redeem myself to the new one. The problem must be when consuming the asmx.

Does this answer your question? Redirect ASMX to another server

No. I have hundreds of projects that I want to consume the new service without having to go one by one changing the destination url.

Enable detailed logging for both IIS and ARR to get more insights into what's happening with the requests and the redirection process.

Added the parameter AllowAutoRedirect = true in the code

Old technology can work badly with URL redirection but you might try to configure IIS as reverse proxy instead.

I leave it as impossible. As the url of the services is saved in the web.config of the projects, I am going to proceed to replace the url in all of them.

With IIS acting as a reverse proxy, your old ASP.NET Webforms applications should be able to transparently access the new ASMX service address, please ensure that all ARR and URL rewrite configurations are applied correctly. If the problem persists, check the IIS logs for more information.
